# How to setup a laravel site in sub folder while main site is a wordpress

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, web, .env

I am having problem setting up a Laravel site on a WordPress site's sub folder.

My site structure is here: - Mainsite/laravelfiles/public

I also have an existing. Htaccess file in main public_html

```
<IfModule security2_module>
    SecRuleRemoveByTag unoeuro
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

In the laravelfiles/public folder, I have this. htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

In public folder, index.php file has these lines

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

In the .env file, I have these lines

```
APP_URL='https://mainsite/laravelfiles'
FRONTEND_URL='https://mainsite/laravelfiles/public'
```

After all, this page not found message appears.

I've tried almost all solutions provided online, including. htaccess, .env, index.php file changing. Clearing cache etc...

Comment: (https://mainsite/laravelfiles/public) returns main page with page not found message

Comment: `https://mainsite/laravelfiles/public` - although presumably `public` should not be part of the visible URL?

Comment: I have set laravelfiles, laravelfiles/resources, laravelfiles/storeage bootstrap/cache folder permissions to 777 but not working still.

Comment: I don't care about how URL looks like currently, just want it working ...

Comment: "with page not found message" - Is the "page not found msg generated by Laravel, WordPress or Apache?

Comment: we achieved this setup by configuring the nginx config file accordingly, what webserver are you using?

Comment: If `public` is to be present in the URL then there isn't anything more to configure with the server. This looks like a Laravel issue (depending on what is generating the 404 response). But shouldn't `APP_URL` include `/public`? (If, however, you wish to remove `/public` from the URL then you need an additional `.htaccess` file in the `/laravelfiles` directory to rewrite requests to `/public` and then Laravel needs to be changed accordingly.)

Comment: It uses LiteSpeed server.

Comment: "Page not found" message is generated by Wordpress, because it shows the main wordpress site with this message.

Comment: What if you request `https://example.com/laravelfiles/public/index.php` directly? If you are seeing the WP 404 response then it would seem the `/laravelfiles/public/.htaccess` file is either being completely ignored (in the subdirectory) or mod_rewrite inheritance has been configured to inherit from the parent config first (assuming LiteSpeed works the same as Apache in this respect) - neither of which should happen, unless additional restrictions have been placed on your server. Is this a _shared_ server environment?

Comment: Wordpress also recreates the htaccess file if I delete it.

Comment: Using the direct request to index page also result in 'page not found'

Comment: I also tried deleting both htaccess files in pubic_html and in laravelfiles folder. But same result.

Comment: I need to check whether it a shared server environment or not!

Comment: Yes, WordPress will generally recreate its `.htaccess` file if deleted. If you are requesting `/laravelfiles/public/index.php` and you are still seeing the WP 404 response then something odd is happening?! That file definitely exists I assume? Is this perhaps a dedicated/restricted WordPress-only environment?? "I also tried deleting both htaccess files in pubic_html and in laravelfiles folder. But same result." - (I assume you mean `/laravelfiles/public` folder?) Deleting that `.htaccess` file you would expect the same result (as it would seem to be ignored currently anyway).

Comment: Yes I think it is strict Wordpress environment. I have to contact the admin for further details . . . Thanks for the help. I'll get back to you with more info . . .

Comment: Is a must to create the Laravel project inside the WP project? Seems like a bad idea, in my opinion, the Laravel project should be in its own environment. I'd create the Laravel project in another instance and get its IP, then create a subdomain in the DNS (app.mydomain.com) and set the value to the IP you just got from the instance

Comment: I was provided with this environment, I'm working on it...

Comment: I was optimizing wrong folder, names are similar. Once I optimized the right folder it worked. Thank you all !